# Subexpressions in Handlebars

Tags: javascript, templates, handlebars.js

Why expressions 1, 2 and 4 are working as expected, but not 3 and 5

HTML:

```
<script id="template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
<ol>
    <li>{{dash 'abc' (concat a b)}}</li>
    <li>{{dash d (concat a b)}}</li>
    <li>{{dash c.c (concat a b)}}</li>
    <li>{{dash (concat a b) c.c}}</li>
    <li>{{dash (concat a e.e) c.c}}</li>
</ol>
</script>
<div id="rendered"></div>
```

JavaScript:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('dash', function(a, b) {
    return a + "-" + b;
});

Handlebars.registerHelper('concat', function(a, b) {
    return a + b;
});

var template = Handlebars.compile($("#template").html());
$("#rendered").html(template({a: 'a', b:'b', c:{c:'c'}, d:'d', e: {e: 'e'}}));
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/beradrian/6T8ah/

The actual result is

```
1. abc-ab
2. d-ab
3. c-[object Object]
4. ab-c
5. ae-[object Object]
```

I filled in a bug report at Handlebars: https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/issues/800.

Answer (score 0):

### Don't use path (dot) notation in first parameter in helper

If the first parameter is in path (dot) notation, the second parameter is ignored and replaced by a reference to the first parameter's root path.

This is definitely a bug and it looks like a fix was released in v2.0.0-beta.1 according to the comments on your bug report.

If you're not using that version, the workaround is to place the helper inside a `{{#with}}` block and remove the path notation from that first parameter.

*Note: While you can't use `prop.subprop` notation in the first parameter, you can use `../prop` with no problem.*

For example:

```
<script id="template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    <ol>
        <li>{{dash 'abc' (concat a b)}}</li>
        <li>{{dash d (concat a b)}}</li>
        <li>{{#with c}}
            {{dash c (concat ../a ../b)}}
            {{/with}}</li>
        <li>{{dash (concat a b) c.c}}</li>
        <li>{{#with e}}
            {{dash (concat ../a e) ../c.c}}
            {{/with}}</li>
    </ol>
</script>
<div id="rendered"></div>
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gfullam/oezb1539/